# How did you prove this equality with order axioms?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, real-numbers

During my Calculus course the teacher left us an exercise that he demonstrated, but his procedure did not convince me at all and I'm looking for a convincing way to prove the following equality:

Prove that if $a,b>0$, such that $a+b=1$ then:

$(a+\frac{1}{a})^{2}+(b+\frac{1}{b})^{2}\geq\frac{25}{2}$

We were using the axioms of order and elemental properties of order to try to prove it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'his procedure'?

Comment: please edit your question to reproduce the method used by your teacher.